# How to get multiple implementations of a single AsyncTask class in Android?

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask

I am developing an **Android** application, where most of my activities are fetching content from a **MySQL** database separately, through an **http** request.
For this, I am required to add the **AsyncTask** class separately to each such activity.

Is there a possibility that I may use a common AsyncTask class for all such data fetching and create their objects separately in the activities and fetch data based on the parameters?

Comment: you can create a inner class extending Async task, then in constructor you can pass url and required params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can create separate class extending `AsyncTask` for making HTTP requests, which will take appropriate parameters and re-use it in many activities. You don't have to create nested private classes in each activity. You can use input parameters of `AsyncTask` in `doInBackground(parameters)` method. See documentation of `AsyncTask` at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Below, you can see very simple example of using `AsyncTask` with some pseudo-code:

```
public class DownloadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
  protected String doInBackground(String address) {
    // you should have method for performing HTTP request
    // and return result - in this case as String
    String result = performHttpRequest(address);
    return result;
  }    

  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // this method is executed after downloading result
    // now, you can perform some action - e.g. display data in a TextView
    myTextView.setText(result);
  }
}
```

In this definition: `AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>` first parameter is type of input parameter (in this case address of the end-point), second parameter is type of progress value (we are not using it in this example), last parameter is type of output value (in our case, HTTP response as String).

When `DownloadDataTask` class is placed in a separate file, you can re-use it in many activities with the following call:

```
new DownloadDataTask().execute(address);
```

Of course, it's very basic example with some pseudo-code. I haven't initialized `TextView` and I haven't provided implementation of `performHttpRequest()` method. You should adjust it to your needs. You can also upgrade this solution and pass reference to a `TextView` or another widget in which your result will be displayed.

Nevertheless, **consider using RxJava** and RxAndroid instead of `AsyncTask`. It will make you app simpler and less error-prone. I do not recommend using `AsyncTask`, because we have many better solutions for Android right now. Regardless of this fact, you decide which solution will be used in your project.

Comment: thanks for the help. since I am new at this, the official reference guide is still a little overwhelming. could you explain with some example?

Comment: @HarshPoddar I've edited my answer and added example. I hope, it's quite clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in much the same way as you would with any other `Class` - create a separate class file that extends `AsyncTask` and create an object where it's required.

For more flexibility, you could declare the class `abstract` and use an unknown type parameter, so that you can adjust it as your requirements change.

```
public abstract class MyTask<T> extends AsyncTask<T, Void, Void>{    

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("Tag", "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Log.i("Tag", "onPostExecute");
    }
}
```

And then, whenever you want to create an instance:

```
MyTask<String> mt = null; //Or URL etc.    
//...
if (mt == null) {
    mt = new MyTask() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
mt.execute(params);
```

Comment: This technique also nice.
But I found the above technique better suited for my application